# about ubuntu desktop12 ssh

Tags: windows, ssh

In Ubuntu, ssh server is ok.
At `ps -e | grep ssh` has hdserver.
But can't connect `ssh` from Windows. Wrong info with "time out connect".
The server is in the same LAN.

In Ubuntu, I use `ssh name@ip` and successfully connects to the server.

Who can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What do you mean by "At `ps -e | grep ssh` has hdserver"? What is hdserver? How many machines do you actually have? You can't connect to the server using Windows, but you can connect to it using another Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't have a SSH program AFAIK, Try using Putty, its free, and it works great on all of my machines (Free BSD, Debian, AntiX,Ubuntu Server. CrunchBang {#!] <-lol)

You can get Putty here:
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html